# Autonumber comparision in JDBC

Tags: sql, jdbc-odbc

I have an Auto Number(Random number) field in access database. Now i want to compare the input i have got from user with that autonumber field using JDBC. Which datatype i should use for comparing?

Answer (score 0):

Access database have `Number` date type. You should use that.

In JDBC, in `PreparedStatement` query parameter you have to use `setInt`